# Efficient algorithm for indexing 2D angles

Tags: algorithm, 2d, trigonometry

I'm optimizing a bigger algorithm for fun (its to do with line of sight calculations). One part of this algorithm is indexing a bunch of 2D vertices by their angle in regards to a point of origin. Thing is though, I don't actually need precise angles, all I need is to reliably detect whether one primitive overlaps another in angular terms, therefore expensive trigonometry is out and cheap pseudomath is in!

This is the one I came up with myself:

```
    orientation(x, y) {
        const sign = 1 - 2 * (x * y < 0);
        return x / (x * sign + y) + ((x < 0) + (sign < 0)) * 2; 
    }
```

It works well, it spits out a value from 0 to 4 and if I have a primitive that for example extends from orientation 0 - 2 and another that goes from 1 - 3 then I know for a fact that they are potentially overlapping and that more expensive calculations may need to be made between them.

You may be tempted to suggest AABB or spatial trees to me - I'm already doing those in earlier stages.

The question is - is there a more efficient function for getting a single scalar value out of a 2D vector that represents its angle in regards to (0, 0)? The only quality this value needs to guarantee is that overlapping ranges need to be actually overlapping in real angles too.

Comment: Which two lines are you considering for an angle extended by a 2D vertex?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur I have a point of view "p" and from this one point I draw a line to every vertex that I am considering. Then I imagine a ray from "p" towards some arbitrary fixed direction, (1, 0) for example. The angles would form between the lines and the ray. The x and y that enter my function for example would be vertex[i] - p

Comment: "from orientation 0 - 2 and another that goes from 1 - 3 "  <-- would u mind to share the exact value of both x&y pair that is confirmed to be 'overlapped'?